# calculate $\pi_1(\mathbb D-\{(0,0)\})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm interested in calculating $\pi_1(\mathbb D-\{(0,0)\})$.

My guess would be that $\mathbb D-\{(0,0)\}$ is homotpic to $S^1$ and so the fundamental group would be $\mathbb Z$. Am I right?
How would one show that the spaces are homotopic?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: try to construct a deformation retract of $\mathbb{D}-\{ (0,0) \}$ onto the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

We wish to define maps 
\begin{align*}
f&: \Bbb S^1\to\Bbb D^\prime & g&:\Bbb D^\prime\to \Bbb S^1
\end{align*}
such that $f\circ g\simeq 1_{\Bbb D^\prime}$ and $g\circ f\simeq 1_{\Bbb S^1}$.

Using our intuition, we may define $f$ and $g$ by the formulas
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x & g(x) &= \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}
\end{align*}
Now, we wish to construct maps 
\begin{align*}
F &: I\times\Bbb D^\prime\to\Bbb D^\prime & G&:I\times\Bbb S^1\to\Bbb S^1
\end{align*}
where $I=[0,1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
F(0,x) &= (f\circ g)(x)            & G(0,x)   &= (g\circ f)(x) \\
       &= \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert} &          &= \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert} \\
&&&=x \\
F(1,x) &= x                        & G(1,x)   &= x
\end{align*} 
Clearly $G(\lambda,x)=x$ works. Can you define $F(\lambda,x)$?